# Prevent Release Trigger on Gated Check-in build

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration, azure-devops, continuous-deployment

How to stop the release trigger on Gated check-in build which doesn;t produce any artifact?

I have a build definition with Gated check-in enabled. In Publish and Publish Artifact Steps I have set the condition as following:

> **ne(variables['Build.Reason'],'CheckInShelveset')**

which means - if the build was triggered by Gated check-in, do not run this step.

I do not see any files in drop folder of this build run but the release is being triggered as soon the gated build completes running.

I've added images for reference purposes.

- Image 1 shows the configuration of build definition.
- Image 2 shows the "publish" steps are not running as it's a gated build.
- Image 3 shows the release being triggered from the same build even when there is nothing in drop (output) folder!

This is very surprising to me. Any help?

Thanks!

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

[image: Image 3]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an option on the first environment where you can set an Artifact filter, enter Include `TriggerRelease`:

[image: Add artefact filter]

By tagging your build (in case it's not a gated check-in), you can prevent the release from triggering. You can run a small magic log command to set the tag in the build:

```
Write-Host "##vso[build.addbuildtag]TriggerRelease"
```

Or you can [use a build task from the following extension to have a build tag itself](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=andremarques023.DiagnosticTasks):

[image: Tag build from pipeline]

Comment: thanks @jessehouwing, that helped sort this out. The PowerShell script worked really well instead of the Markeplace extension.

Write-Host "##vso[build.addbuildtag]Automatd"