# TFS 2015 Gated Build is creating a Build and Triggering Release Job

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015, azure-pipelines

We are working on TFS 2015 Update 1

The same Job is triggering CI / Gated / Scheduled Build

I want CI/Scheduled build to Publish Artifact
Unable to find a way to disable Build Step Dynamically
I am calling a Powershell Script before 'Publish Build Artifact' Step and trying to find a solution to access the next Step and Set it to 'Skip'

But I have seen even when the Drop folder is empty, the Release (CI/CD) triggers as the Gated Job is creating a Build

Is there a way to avoid Gated Job to create a Build
or to avoid Release Job to trigger in case of Gated Build

Answer (score 0):

In TFS 2015 update 1 I think you're way too far behind. There are solutions for later versions. In your case, you'd need a separate Build Definition for the gated build and if my memory serves me right, you don't have the task group option yet. Task Groups were introduced in TFS 2017, they would at least allow you to share process and variables between separate build definitions.

You're on an unsupported TFS version, in any case, TFS 2015 update 1 was replaced by TFS 2015 update 3.1 any versions between TFS 2015.0 and 2015.3.1 are unsupported and TFS 2015 update 1 contains a number of XSS security vulnerabilities that were fixed in TFS 2015.3.1 as well as in TFS 2017.0.1, 2017.3.1 and 2018.1. This would be a good time to upgrade and make the jump.

In TFS 2018 this would be possible [with an artefact tag filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/release/triggers?view=vsts#env-triggers):

- [Prevent Release Trigger on Gated Check-in build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49531359/prevent-release-trigger-on-gated-check-in-build/49532745#49532745)

One option that remains available is to turn off the CI trigger of the release workflow and then from a powershell script, conditionally trigger the release from the build.

Comment: Using Rest-API, I am able to disable the 'Publish Build Artifact' step dynamically (if Gated Checkin - Disable; Else Enable) in the previous task. But still the Release is getting triggered . Is there any chance to not to Trigger the Release in case of Gated Checkin (TFS 2015)

Comment: No. Upgrade to a later version of TFS or split your gated build from CI.