# Prevent added artifact to Release on Gated build

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, artifact

In order to save on the maintenance of build definition I create one build for Gated & Publish.

I also create a release that triger when my build run as deploy (As described in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49531359/prevent-release-trigger-on-gated-check-in-build))

When build run as deploy (not Gated) there are another tasks that run during the build:

- Publish Build Artifacts - upload artifacts
- Update Build Name - change the build name to "Auditing [Version]" format
- Add build tag - Use to triger release

When I am try to create release manuly I get list of artifacts, some of the artifact are resualt of gated build.

In the image bellow I market the gated build.

[image: Create Release]

I'm interested in keeping a clean list, is there a way to prevent from tfs to add gated build to my articact list

I am working with TFS 2018.2 On-Prem.

Thanks In advance for all.

Comment: do want those tasks will be executed in the Gated build?

Comment: It passable, I just want to prevent from TFS to add build without artifacts to release .